# Spark struct represented by OneHotEncoder

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a data frame with two columns,

```
+---+-------+
| id|  fruit|
+---+-------+
|  0|  apple|
|  1| banana|
|  2|coconut|
|  1| banana|
|  2|coconut|
+---+-------+
```

also I have a universal List with all the items,

```
fruitList: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(apple, coconut, banana)
```

now I want to create a new column in the dataframe with an array of  1's,0's, where 1 represent the item exist and 0  if the item doesn't present for that row.

Desired Output

```
    +---+-----------+
    | id|  fruitlist|
    +---+-----------+
    |  0|  [1,0,0]  |
    |  1| [0,1,0]   |
    |  2|[0,0,1]    |
    |  1| [0,1,0]   |
    |  2|[0,0,1]    |
    +---+-----------+
```

This is something I tried,

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer}

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "apple"),
  (1, "banana"),
  (2, "coconut"),
  (1, "banana"),
  (2, "coconut")
)).toDF("id", "fruit")

df.show
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val fruitList = df.select(collect_set("fruit")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0)
print(fruitList)
```

I tried to solve this with OneHotEncoder but the result was something like this after converting to dense vector, which is not what I needed.

```
    +---+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
| id|  fruit|fruitIndex|     fruitVec|       vd|
+---+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
|  0|  apple|       2.0|    (2,[],[])|[0.0,0.0]|
|  1| banana|       1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|[0.0,1.0]|
|  2|coconut|       0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|[1.0,0.0]|
|  1| banana|       1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|[0.0,1.0]|
|  2|coconut|       0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|[1.0,0.0]|
+---+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your last sentence. The results in the last table you show are sparse.

Comment: @eliasah, I have edited the question with correct dense vector representation.

Comment: Your vectors have a length of 2 because you used the default parameter `dropLast=True`on your OneHotEncoder. But anyway it will not keep the order you want (because StringIndexer orders items by occurence). Use @Ramesh Maharjan answer

Comment: @Arius, thank you for that tip, setting  encoder.setDropLast(false) will show the full vector elements.Will the onehotestimator maintain the order?

Comment: @Masterbuilder Yes the OneHotEncoder will, but the StringIndexer before will break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a collection as

```
val fruitList: Seq[String] = Array("apple", "coconut", "banana")
```

Then you can either do it using *inbuilt functions* or *udf function*

## inbuilt functions (array, when and lit)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("fruitList", array(fruitList.map(x => when(lit(x) === col("fruit"),1).otherwise(0)): _*)).show(false)
```

## udf function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def containedUdf = udf((fruit: String) => fruitList.map(x => if(x == fruit) 1 else 0))

df.withColumn("fruitList", containedUdf(col("fruit"))).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+-------+---------+
|id |fruit  |fruitList|
+---+-------+---------+
|0  |apple  |[1, 0, 0]|
|1  |banana |[0, 0, 1]|
|2  |coconut|[0, 1, 0]|
|1  |banana |[0, 0, 1]|
|2  |coconut|[0, 1, 0]|
+---+-------+---------+
```

**udf functions are easy to understand and straight forward, dealing with primitive datatypes but should be avoided if optimized and fast inbuilt functions are available to do the same task**

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Would you care, please, explaining this to me Ramesh ? I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: what didn't you understand? @eliasah.

Comment: I didn't understand the question and the relation to your answer. I'm not question what you said here. Nothing to argue about.

Comment: I just tried to help the OP generate the expected output. thats all. In his output (he has tried to generate 1 for matching string and 0 for non matching). I hope its clear.

Comment: Thanks for explaining to me what the OP wants. :)